# Total DC resistance of thin-film resistor with truncated contact pads

Tags: resistors

I would like to calculate the DC resistance across a rectangular patch of resistive material with contact pads that are less than the resistor width.  The resistive material is a thin film with a sheet resistivity given in ohms per square (S).  If the contact pads were the same width as the resistor width the total DC resistance (R) would simply be the number of squares in the sheet multiplied by the sheet resistivity, ie. if P=W then R=S*(W/L).  However, the fringing currents would seem to create a more complex situation.[image]

Comment: The obvious way is to solve it numerically. Do you just want an answer? It can be physically modeled.

Comment: +1, if you want to be precise you'll need a simulator such as comsol